# Is there way to use is.na in R with column number references?

Tags: r, data.table, bioinformatics, na

I'm building an R package in bioinformatics and I have a data table I have where one of the column names is variable, it will be based off the input genomic data. I have a line with a conditional where I need two conditions: one column in a row is NA and another column is greater than some number the user will give.

I've tried to use is.na() with something like mergeframe_dt[,2] where I specify column # rather than the typical column name.

Typically, something like this would work:

```
mergeframe_dt[is.na(new)&Reads>5, new := factor(0)]
```

But the problem is that the 'new' column name is variable, it will be different in every case. Earlier in my code I basically set it to the name of the genomic file the user would input.

Ideally, I want something that works like this where it checks if the second column of the data table mergeframe_dt is NA and if the 'Reads' column is greater than 5.

```
mergeframe_dt<-as.data.table(mergeframe)
mergeframe_dt[is.na(mergeframe_dt[,2])&Reads>5, new := factor(0)]
```

I also tried this but it also didn't work:

```
mergeframe_dt[is.na(mergeframe_dt$(colnames(mergeframe_dt)[2]))&Reads>5, new := factor(0)]
```

Errors:
 Example 1:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(mergeframe_dt, is.na(mergeframe_dt[, 2]) & Reads >  : 
  i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please report to data.table issue tracker if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657.
```

Example 2:

```
Error: unexpected '(' in "mergeframe_dt[is.na(mergeframe_dt$("
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only base R you could do something like this:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(var = as.factor(c(1, NA, NA, 2)),
                 Reads = 4:7)

new <- "var"

expr <- substitute(DT[is.na(var_name) & Reads > 5, var_name := factor(0)],
                   list(var_name = as.name(new)))

eval(expr)

print(DT)
    var Reads
1:    1     4
2: <NA>     5
3:    0     6
4:    2     7
```

Comment: If OP has a column number instead of a name, could do `new <- names(DT)[num]`.

Answer (score 0):

A idiomatic way is to use `.I`

```
mergeframe_dt <- data.table(new=c(1,NA), Reads=c(1,6))
v <- "new"
mergeframe_dt[mergeframe_dt[, .I[is.na(get(v)) & Reads > 5]], (v) := 0L]
```

I am expecting `..v` to work as well instead of `get(v)`, maybe my understanding of `..` is not correct.